# ElasticSearch: How to reload Hunspell dictionary without restart

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I somehow reload Hunspell dictionaries without restarting my nodes?

We quite frequently update our dictionaries, and I would very much like to not restart all our nodes just because of these tiny changes.